# Invoke method on generic base class using Reflection via derived type

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to invoke a method on a base class via reflection, but `GetMethods(...)` does not find the method.

My base class looks like this:

```
public abstract class MyBase<S, T> where S : class, new()
                                   where T : ILocalizableTitle
{
    public IEnumerable<T> For(string systemLangCode)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> For(Person person)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> For(CultureInfo cultureInfo, long tenantId)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllMyTypes()
    {
        var thisType = new StackFrame().GetMethod().DeclaringType;

        return (
                   from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                   where t.IsClass
                         && t.Namespace == thisType?.Namespace
                         && t.BaseType?.Name == thisType?.Name
                   select t).ToList();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'm obtaining a derived type via Reflection...

```
var myDerivedType = MyBase<object, ILocalizableTitle>.GetAllMyTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == forTypeByName);
```

From `myDerivedType` I expected to see the `Reset` method by using the following:

```
var publicMethods = myDerivedType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
```

But `publicMethods` is empty.

How can I get and invoke the `Reset` method if I have the derived type, *i.e.*, an instance of System.Type representing the derived type?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question. You call the `Reset()` method on a derived type *by calling it*. It's inherited.

Comment: I don't have an instance of the derived type. I've got the _derived type_.

Comment: Please edit your post. Your last sentence is "How can I get and invoke the `Reset` method if I have an ***instance*** of a derived type?" If you do not have an object instance, you cannot invoke any member unless it is static. Can you explain a bit more what you are doing?

Comment: Ok, point taken. Post has been edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the msdn about the [Type.GetMethods method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetMethods_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_):

> You must specify either BindingFlags.Instance or BindingFlags.Static in order to get a return.

Changing your call to `publicMethods = myDerivedType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance);` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a unit test which repeats the scenario you're attempting:

```
[TestClass]
public class ReflectionTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ReflectionDiscoversBaseClassMethod()
    {
        var inheritedType = typeof(InheritedClass);
        var inheritedTypeMethods = inheritedType.GetMethods(
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        Assert.IsTrue(
            inheritedTypeMethods.Any(method => method.Name == "ImplementedMethod"));
    }
}

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public void ImplementedMethod()
    { }
}

public class InheritedClass : BaseClass { }
```

The test fails, which validates what you're seeing.

I changed it to this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ReflectionDiscoversBaseClassMethod()
{
    var inheritedType = typeof(InheritedClass);
    var inheritedTypeMethods = inheritedType.GetMethods(
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    Assert.IsTrue(inheritedTypeMethods.Any(method => method.Name == "ImplementedMethod"));
}
```

...and it passes.

It's necessary to specify `BindingFlags.Instance` so it knows whether you're looking for instance or static methods.